# Inline editing lightning-datatable bar

Tags: lightning-datatable, datatable, inline, inline-editing

I have a lightning datatable that has columns editables, I wanna to suppress the bottom bar and with a button get the values, but it's not working, because only the last column that was filled remain filled, the other ones are been erase the values..

**HTML**

```
<lightning-datatable
    key-field="id"
    data={products}
    columns={columnsProducts}
    draft-values={draftValues}
    oncellchange={handleCellChange}
    hide-checkbox-column="true"
    suppress-bottom-bar>
</lightning-datatable>
<button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={saveHandleAction}>
    Adicionar
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
handleCellChange(event) {
  const draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
  this.draftValues = draftValues;
}

saveHandleAction(event) {
  this.products.forEach(item => {
    const match = this.draftValues.find(item2 => item.id === item2.id);
    if (match) {
      this.output.push({ ...item, ...match });
    }
  });
}
```